# sonar-maven-plugin fails to recognise jdk version from "maven.compiler.release"

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, maven-compiler-plugin, sonar-maven-plugin

Behaviour of sonar-maven-plugin varies when `maven-compiler-plugin` is/isn't defined. I spent some time to find out the proper setting.

Create a simple Java maven project and keep the `pom.xml` simple.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>testing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Execution

```
mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:<version>:sonar -Dsonar.login=<token>
```

Case 1:

- `sonarqube-maven-plugin` version: `3.7.0.1746`
- `pom.xml` with `maven.compiler.release` defined.
- `maven-compiler-plugin` is **NOT** defined in `pom.xml`

Result:

```
Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): 5
```

Case 2:

- `sonarqube-maven-plugin` version: `3.7.0.1746`
- `pom.xml` with `maven.compiler.release` defined
- `pom.xml` with `maven.compiler.source` defined
- `maven-compiler-plugin` is **NOT** defined in `pom.xml`

Result:

(It means the plugin can only get the version from `source` instead of `release`)

```
Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): 17
```

Case 3:

- `sonarqube-maven-plugin` version: `3.7.0.1746`
- `pom.xml` with `maven.compiler.release` defined
- `maven-compiler-plugin` (3.8.1) is defined

Result:

(No idea why the version changes when maven compiler plugin is defined.)

```
Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): 6
```

Case 4:

- `sonarqube-maven-plugin` version: `3.7.0.1746`
- `pom.xml` with `maven.compiler.release` defined
- `maven-compiler-plugin` (3.10.1) is defined

Result:

(No idea why the version changes when **different** version of maven compiler plugin is defined.)

```
Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): 7
```

Case 5:

- `sonarqube-maven-plugin` version: `3.9.1.2184`
- `pom.xml` with `maven.compiler.release` defined
- `maven-compiler-plugin` is **NOT** defined in `pom.xml`

Result:

(Upgrading sonar maven plugin doesn't help.)

```
Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper setting

- `sonarqube-maven-plugin` with version `3.8.0` or above.
- Define `maven-compiler-plugin` in `pom.xml` with version `3.6.0` or above.

Execution:

```
mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar -Dsonar.login=<token>
```

`pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>testing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```